# Should I cut concrete panel into strips, and rings with hooks, or leave it in long strips?

Tags: vegetables, trellis

I've decided to build all of my trellises out of concrete panel, and was wondering if I should cut it into strips, and make easy to handle panels, and rings that hook together (at the support posts), or leave the panels grow flat to keep the various plants grow right next to the edges of the panels and move them in the fall in the back of the truck. I know both ways would work, but what way would work better for the long run?

I'll be putting it up once a year until it will be no longer able to support its load properly

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do this. I'm not sure there is a "best" way but here's my opinion:

It is light stuff - maybe 5# for a 4x7 piece of it.  They sell them at the Home Depot in 42"x84" pieces and they're about 5# maybe.

I like panels I can easily handle by myself - 12' wide is as wide as I would go.  A 50' roll would yield four ~12' sections (each cut you make will remove about 6" of length if they are 6"x10" holes) so you'll have, roughly lengths of 12'.

At 12' I'd drive a T-post or a U-post every 6' to create a sturdy trellis.  Then just buy a roll of galvanized wire and wire them up to the posts.  You could attach them any number of ways.  I end up having a lot of twine from hay bales here that I save and that works well enough for the season.  At the end of the season I cut the twine and toss it.

Of course you can cut them whatever length you want.  My ground isn't necessarily flat so panels let me adjust to the terrain.  With the roll I found it buckles just a bit - not a big deal but I also had to roll it up and hump it around the farm in a big roll... not ideal.

Comment: i'm thinking about 150' long in 4 foot lengths then 1'x1' around to hold up the "caging plants" then cutting it into pieces, off a roll, so I'm not sure how to work with full rolls, and using a lot of u posts for marking the driveway in the winter.

Comment: I'm thinking my design has cages right next to flat panel also so the vines/lettuces can interact with the caged plants well also